# section of .hgrc

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I installed Mercurial correctly on the local network and now I have hgusers and when someone tries to "push" he is asked for password, if he enters the correct one the password is accepted.

The question is how can I enter the username and password once on each user's .hgrc file? I tried the following but it's not working:

```
[auth]
localhost.prefix = http://192.168.0.1/hg/
localhost.username = frodo
localhost.password = ok123
```

I'm getting:

```
searching for changes
abort: authorization failed
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like you've got the correct syntax. Two potential problems:

(a) Perhaps you have the wrong value for the prefix. **Should you actually have https rather than http?**

(b) Are you sure that the username and passwords are correct on the remote machine?

#### Can you ssh into the server with the username and password?

Additionally, I have a long answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584407/how-to-save-username-and-password-with-mercurial/2584425#2584425)

#### What worked for me

```
[ui]
username=Chris McCauley <chris.mccauley@mydomain.com>

[auth]
repo.prefix = https://server/repo_path
repo.username = username
repo.password = password
```

Chris

Answer (score 3):

Here is why it did not work and how it should be configured:

You can either specify 'schemes' option or skip it. 'Schemes' option defaults to 'https'. Thus, if you don't include scheme into 'prefix' option **and** don't explicitly specify 'schemes' option, you will have this:

```
# you specify:
[auth]
repo.prefix = server/repo_path
repo.username = username
repo.password = password

# you get:
[auth]
repo.prefix = server/repo_path
repo.username = username
repo.password = password
repo.schemes = https
```

Resulting config does not match `http://server/repo_path`, and authentication does not work.

I recommend to always specify scheme either in prefix or in 'schemes' configuration option for disambiguation.

And it is explained in the [docs](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth), but you have to read it very carefully to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a relatively recent version of mercurial.  I don't think the `[auth]` section existed before 1.6.

As a fallback you can always put username and password right into HTTP URLs (works with any HTTP site):

```
http://frodo:ok123@192.168.0.1/hg/
```

but if you can get it working `[auth]` is the cleaner route.