# python import seems to behave differently in mercurial_keyring.py file

Tags: python, mercurial, import, abort

A bizarre `import` error is preventing me from installing a mercurial extension.

I'm trying to get the `mercurial_keyring` extension running so that I don't have to type in my user name and password every time I use mercurial for a project.

I'm using Python 2.7.1. I installed mercurial with the binary provided at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/.

I installed `keyring` and `mercurial_keyring` with `pip`.

I first tried to add the extension by adding this to `~/.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
...
mercurial_keyring =
```

as indicated in the installation instructions [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension#Installation). However, I got the following error:

```
*** failed to import extension mercurial_keyring: No module named mercurial_keyring
```

From the same installation instructions, I tried pointing mercurial directly to the `mercurial_keyring.py` file, which worked.

```
[extensions]
...
hgext.mercurial_keyring = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial_keyring.py
```

And things seemed to be moving along.

However, when I try to execute any mercurial commands requiring my password so that it will be saved by `keyring` (*e.g.* `hg pull`, `hg push`) I get the error

```
abort: No module named keyring!
```

The most confusing part is that there is a clear

```
import keyring
```

in line 28 of `mercurial_keyring.py` that is resolved without any problems. In fact, any `import keyring` succeeds outside classes and methods and fails inside them!

Just for the sake of thoroughness, I'll mention that this error arises in the `mercurial_keyring.py` in the `PasswordStore` class in the `get_http_password` method when the following is attempted

```
return keyring.get_password(...)
```

Any thoughts?

I have the feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but I've spent a good deal of time trying to figure this out and google has not been particularly helpful so far. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What output do you get when running `python -m site`? (you'll need to add it to the question, it won't be readable as a comment)

Comment: My current suspicion is that you have a problem with either your 2.7 install or the system 2.6 install, such that mercurial is using one of them, while your manual tests are using the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely, `hg` is running using the system python (2.6) rather than the copy of 2.7 you have installed.

Try installing `mercurial_keyring` and `keyring` under 2.6, and see if that gets things working as expected.

Comment: Yes! I had tried that but it didn't work. I've updated my question to expand on that point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Given the `ImportError` you get when using the standard configuration instructions for `mercurial_keyring`, I'm inclined to go back to my first guess (i.e. `hg` is using the system installation of 2.6, rather than the copy of 2.7 where you installed the extra modules). I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I think the problem is that the binary form the mercurial website installs to the system's Python 2.6, instead of the default one, which was 2.7 in my case. Instead of reverting to 2.6 I've now installed mercurial for python 2.7 with pip. Then I just renamed `/usr/local/bin/hg` to `/usr/local/bin/hg-2.6` and symlinked `/usr/local/bin/hg` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/hg`.

Comment: `Try installing mercurial_keyring and keyring under 2.6, and see if that gets things working as expected.` ... how do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial uses a feature called 'demandimport' which postpones the import of modules, until the first time they are used. So, your

> import keyring

won't fail at that line, but it will wail only when it's used first(i.e)

> return keyring.get_password(...)

Comment: Good to know! Thanks! A quick google search failed to give me a definitive answer or documentation on this. Do you have any reliable sources you could share?

Comment: search in the mercurial-devel arhcives and mercurial wiki. Well I don't know the reason for your actual problem, but just pointing out the reason why import keyring is not failing.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by installing extension with easy install:
sudo easy_install mercurial_keyring

This installs it under the same python that mercurial uses.

Answer (score 1):

@ncoghlan's answer is right (for me, anyway), but incomplete and I don't have enough rep points to comment. (Jeremy S, I think this answers your question.)

To install for a specific version of Python, use the following modifications:
Instead of

```
easy_install keyring
```

Use

```
easy_install-2.6 keyring
```

Same applies for any of the easy_install or other Python commands. I found this from an example for pip here: [How to install a module use pip for specific version of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/how-to-pip-install-to-specific-version-of-python)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue. The issue was I installed mercurial via brew and installed the keyring using pip.
Uninstalling the mercurial in brew and then installing mercurial via pip solved the issue for me.

```
pip install mercurial
```

Answer (score 0):

`import`s in methods are evaluated when they're called, whereas top-level imports are evaluated immediately. The behavior of imports can be modified, have a look at the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) and [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) modules as well as [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path). What is probably happening is that some code at the end of the file (figuratively, may also be a function call on initialization or so) modifies the import behavior by accident or to prevent and notice inadvertent late `import`s.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I installed `Mercurial` via `macports`, but the extension via `pip`. To solve it, I had to install the extension via `macports` as well.

```
sudo port install py-keyring py-mercurial_keyring
```