# Multiple versions of mercurial installed - how to set one to be the default

Tags: python, macos, mercurial

I have two versions of mercurial installed on my Mac OS 10.6.6 and I want to use one of them by default.

I installed mercurial with a binary from [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). I have been running mercurial from the terminal with the `hg` command as it is installed in

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

even though I mostly use Python 2.7.

As a side note, the other Python 2.6 site-packages directory located at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python2.6/si­te-packages
```

did not have mercurial installed.

Using mercurial with 2.6 while mostly using 2.7 for everything else finally caught up to me. (See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173197/).)

I have since installed mercurial (with pip, not the binary from the website) for Python 2.7 in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

but I'm not sure how to indicate which mercurial the `hg` command should use by default. It is using the original 2.6 one right now and I want to use the newer, 2.7 one from now on.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're using virtualenv.  You could just symlink the hg command (is it /usr/bin/hg) to a small script to use python2.7 instead (#!/usr/bin/env python2.7, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I didn't want to get involved with virtualenv if it wasn't necessary. I arrived at the same conclusion - symlinking saved me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenv would be a best solution for you.

http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/06/how-to-contribute-to-mercurial/

See that link. Leave out the contributing part. Just create a virtual env and instead of doing the ln -s commands, do a pip install mercurial there. And the rest should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - in the last few minutes I looked all over for the `hg` command.

It found them in

```
/usr/local/bin/hg
```

which was put there by the binary downloaded from the website some time ago, and

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/hg
```

which was created today when I installed with `pip`.

So I just renamed `/usr/local/bin/hg` to `/usr/local/bin/hg-2.6` and symlinked `/usr/local/bin/hg` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/hg`.