# How to install the pycrypto module for a definite python version

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycrypto

I'm trying to install "Userful MultiSeat-X64-5.0.1 ..." in Ubuntu 13.04 x64, and encountered the following error at the end of the installation:

```
File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher
```

This message means, that there is no pycrypto module.

There is how I should install it:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

But the problem is that userful5 requires python 2.6 to work and ubuntu 13.04 uses python 2.7 as default. I've installed python 2.6, but I don't know how to install the pycrypto module for it.

```
pip install pycrypto
```

returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

As I understand, this module is already installed in python 2.7
But how can I install it to python 2.6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pip install to specific version of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/how-to-pip-install-to-specific-version-of-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use pip for python2.6 (or easy_install)

```
pip-2.6 install pycrypto
```

Use easy_install to get pip-2.6

```
easy_install-2.6 pip
pip-2.6 install pycrypto
```

Comment: "easy_install-2.6 pip" returns:

"No command 'easy_install-2.6' found, did you mean:
 Command 'easy_install-2.7' from package 'python-setuptools' (main)
easy_install-2.6: command not found"

Comment: Downloaded setuptools for python2.6 from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads and it worked.