# Ubuntu - How to install a Python module (BeautifulSoup) on Python 3.3 instead of Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

I have this code (as written in BS4 documentaion):

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When I run the script (using python3) I get the error:

```
  ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

So installed BeatifulSoup by:

```
  sudo pip install BeatifulSoup4
```

But when I try to run the script again I get the same error.
Indeed BS4 is installed in:

```
  BeautifulSoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

But I want to install and use it with python3.3 (as there are other module which are not working with python2.7).

I tried with:

```
  virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.3
```

and then install BS4 again, but nothing solved.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/how-to-pip-install-to-specific-version-of-python

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ubuntu has beautifulsoup packaged. I found it by running apt-cache search

```
$ apt-cache search beautifulsoup
```

I see it has both a 2.7 and 3.3 version in the results. You can get the 3.3 version by installing python3-bs4

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

Answer (score 11):

Use pip3

```
sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

If you cannot run pip3 install it with the [following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip 


xxx@Ubuntu14:~/Desktop$ sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
[sudo] password for xxx:
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz (143kB): 143kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py) egg_info for package BeautifulSoup4

Installing collected packages: BeautifulSoup4
  Running setup.py install for BeautifulSoup4
    Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
    Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
    Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
    Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma

Successfully installed BeautifulSoup4
Cleaning up...
xxx@Ubuntu14:~/Desktop$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

A single command did the trick for me:

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

and then import it as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 1):

I have often referenced the documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

Some examples:

```
 python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2 
 python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7 
 python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3 
 python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I tried to "sudo apt-get install'python3-bs4" it said it was already installed. I ran my program with "python3 program.py" and it worked just fine.