# Installing Python3 Modules on Synology Diskstation stops with errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-module, synology

I fail to install pandas and other modules on my Python3 installation.

System: DS216j, DSM 6.1.3, Marvell Armada

Following instructions from here: 
[Python at Synology, how to get Python3 modules installed and where is Python2.7 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141115/python-at-synology-how-to-get-python3-modules-installed-and-where-is-python2-7)

I could install PIP and I also installed virtualenv and set an ENV in /volume1/Programme/py3k

When I run `pip3 install panda` I get following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gebsk2ej/pandas/
```

The complete output:

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.20.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable lf95
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable fort
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable pathf95
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/setup.py:367: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    /tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 158, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in save_path
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 58, in save_argv
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 84, in override_temp
        yield
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 94, in pushd
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 254, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 49, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/setup.py", line 392, in <module>
        """Custom distutils command subclassed from Cython.Distutils.build_ext
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/setup.py", line 384, in setup_package
        """ % src)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 160, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 674, in get_mathlib_info
        'pandas.tests.io.json',
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-gebsk2ej/pandas/setup.py", line 729, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 335, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 456, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 863, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1141, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1153, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 522, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 672, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 634, in _tmpdir
        yield str(tmpdir)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 672, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 698, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 879, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1118, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1104, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 257, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 182, in save_pkg_resources_state
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 170, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 145, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 158, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in save_path
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 58, in save_argv
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 84, in override_temp
        yield
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 94, in pushd
        yield saved
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 254, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 49, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/setup.py", line 392, in <module>
        """Custom distutils command subclassed from Cython.Distutils.build_ext
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/setup.py", line 384, in setup_package
        """ % src)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/volume1/Programme/py3k/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 160, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2ovt2hrb/numpy-1.13.3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 674, in get_mathlib_info
        'pandas.tests.io.json',
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    /bin/ash: /usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc: No such file or directory
    /bin/ash: /usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc: No such file or directory
```

Do I need to install other packages before (svn, gfortran, etc)? And how would I do it if so?

Or is there another reason why it fails?

/edit

I could install python-dateutil (whl) and pytz (egg), but not pandas and numpy. For pandas and numpy the available wheel packages are only available for x86.

Is this the reason for a failing installation?

How do I build my own wheel for the ARM core used in my system?

edit/

/edit2

It looks like my assumption above is correct. With the help of 
https://github.com/imrehg/arm-wheels
I could install numpy. Unfortunately pandas is not yet available. So I'll try to build it on my own.

edit2/

Thanks for your help!
BMB