# Python modules in Synology DS218j

Tags: python-3.x, linux, server, pip, synology

Recently, I got a synology DS218j. I would like to use it to run a flask server, but I find it very hard to install packages and confusing.

Firstly, I tried to install pip. This already took me quite a while. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51362407/12901331). Then I ran `pip3 install flask`. No problem. But when i tried `pip3 install gevent`:

```
# pip3 install gevent
Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/python3 /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-lvndevnq/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a6' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17, < 2.0 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (237 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached setuptools-53.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=3.0a6
    Using cached Cython-3.0a6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.12.3
    Using cached cffi-1.14.5.tar.gz (475 kB)
  Collecting greenlet<2.0,>=0.4.17
    Using cached greenlet-1.0.0.tar.gz (84 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: cffi, greenlet
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/cffi_31c9d9facb72418a8d12c3175cb4e1d5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/cffi_31c9d9facb72418a8d12c3175cb4e1d5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ylgi5drh
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/cffi_31c9d9facb72418a8d12c3175cb4e1d5/
    Complete output (48 lines):
    unable to execute '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
    unable to execute '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
        the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
        the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
        to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
        tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
        -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
        Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
        the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

        Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
        a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.

    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/c
    /usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -DSYNOPLAT_F_ARMV7 -O2 -fno-diagnostics-show-caret -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=32 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o
    unable to execute '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
    Running setup.py clean for cffi
    Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-08g6kmy0
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/
    Complete output (74 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
    copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_weakref.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_tracing.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_throw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_stack_saved.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator_nested.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_extension_interface.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_cpp.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/test_contextvars.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    running egg_info
    writing src/greenlet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/greenlet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src/greenlet.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/greenlet.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying src/greenlet/greenlet.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
    copying src/greenlet/greenlet.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
    copying src/greenlet/slp_platformselect.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_alpha_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_amd64_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_ios.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_csky_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_mips_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_aix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_linux.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_riscv_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_s390_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x32_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.asm -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.obj -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_msvc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_msvc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
    copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/src
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/src/greenlet
    /usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -DSYNOPLAT_F_ARMV7 -O2 -fno-diagnostics-show-caret -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=32 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c src/greenlet/greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/src/greenlet/greenlet.o
    unable to execute '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
    Running setup.py clean for greenlet
  Failed to build cffi greenlet
  Installing collected packages: pycparser, wheel, setuptools, greenlet, Cython, cffi
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: started
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vmmiaprv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-lvndevnq/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-lvndevnq/overlay/include/python3.8/greenlet
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/
      Complete output (74 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_weakref.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_tracing.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_throw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_stack_saved.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator_nested.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_extension_interface.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_cpp.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_contextvars.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      running egg_info
      writing src/greenlet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/greenlet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/greenlet.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/greenlet.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      writing manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/slp_platformselect.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_alpha_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_amd64_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_ios.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_csky_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_mips_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_aix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_linux.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_riscv_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_s390_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x32_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.asm -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.obj -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_msvc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_msvc.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_unix.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/greenlet/tests
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/src
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/src/greenlet
      /usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -DSYNOPLAT_F_ARMV7 -O2 -fno-diagnostics-show-caret -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=32 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c src/greenlet/greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/src/greenlet/greenlet.o
      unable to execute '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3okrdxbo/greenlet_018865cd102643d6aae5e26174a80901/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vmmiaprv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-lvndevnq/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-lvndevnq/overlay/include/python3.8/greenlet Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/50/1b1175ea3a269b5fa3f0f7fed11149888180695bef5fbf568adbb196efaf/gevent-21.1.2.tar.gz#sha256=520cc2a029a9eef436e4e56b007af7859315cafa21937d43c1d5269f12f2c981 (from https://pypi.org/simple/gevent/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/python3 /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-lvndevnq/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a6' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17, < 2.0 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It says that I don't have `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc` installed. Or it is the python module `distutils`'s problem.

Next, I looked the location of the python3 executable.

```
# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

But there is another one in `volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin`.

```
root@CTNAS:volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin# ls
pip  pip3  pip3.8  python3  python3.8  wheel
```

I uninstalled the python3 and the "python module" (python2) I got from the DSM package center. Looks like there's another python2 in the DSM?

```
# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, May 10 2019, 03:01:38)
[GCC 4.9.3 20150311 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

At this point, I am very confused by the DSM. Strange. I wonder if it is even possible to use python properly in this synology machine. If it is not at all possible, maybe I need to switch to using Apache.

Comment: I am dealing with similar problems. I can't install pandas as it tries to compile, then fails, missing the same arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc crosscompiler. Could not find any wheel files for pandas that is built for the DS218j (armada38x) architecture. Did you figure out how to solve your problem?

Comment: No. I switched to cloud hosting instead.