# Python Data Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I am new to python. I have various versions of python installed in my Mac.

The pandas is installed in python 3.5. I want to use python 2.7. However when I do

import pandas

It says:

ImportError: No module named pandas

I tried pip install pandas but it is installing in python3.5

Can anyone suggest me how I can install modules for specific python

Tanya

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Comment: If you need to use multiple versions of Python, I recommend installing Anaconda or Miniconda: https://www.anaconda.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a `virtual environment` and get started with the `Python` version you want to work on. Link to [Documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv)

You may also follow easy instructions for getting your choice of `Python` version on `IPython Notebook` as well. You may follow Step 1-4 in this [documentation](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html) for `virtual env` and `Python 2.7`