# How do I make cmake find PyQt5 to build krita?

Tags: python, makefile, cmake, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm building krita from source and any time I run `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Path/to/PyQt5` or `cmake .. -DPYQT_SIP_DIR_OVERRIDE=Path/to/PyQt5` I get this warning and it doesn't find `PyQt5`:

```
The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * PyQt5 (required version >= 5.6.0), Python bindings for Qt5., <https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5>
```

When I run locate or find it shows I have `PyQt5` in places such as:

- `~/anaconda3/share/sip/PyQt5`
- `/usr/share/sip/PyQt5`
- `~/anaconda3/share/sip/PyQt5`
- `~/anaconda3/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py36h0386399_5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5`
- `/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/PyQt5`
- `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5`

I've tried the first three but they dont work. More info:I installed `python-qt-devel` from the fedora repository.

What am I missing that I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for which Python version PyQt5 is installed.

In my system, PyQt5 was installed for Python 3.9. However, `cmake` used Python 3.10, and it couldn't find PyQt5. Installing PyQt5 for Python 3.10 solved the problem.

See: [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10919569/13132898)