# How to pip uninstall a package installed using a git project URL?

Tags: python, pip, bluejeans

I've tried following the installation instructions for the BlueJeans meetings REST API (https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings/tree/master/libs/python), using the command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo
```

The `pip freeze` command confirms that I've installed it:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ pip freeze
BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi==1.0.0
certifi==2018.4.16
python-dateutil==2.7.3
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.23
```

However, in the iPython shell, I'm unable to import `BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ ipython
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0891de0c20ce> in <module>()
----> 1 import BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi'
```

This is in my local environment, but I've also installed it in a [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) environment, in which case I was required to provide an egg, which I did by appending `#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi` to the Git project URL. If I do this straight away, I get 'requirement already satisfied':

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ pip install git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
Requirement already satisfied: BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi from git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.15 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (2.7.3)
```

Therefore, I'd like to try to first uninstall BlueJeans and re-install it specifying the egg. However, if I try to uninstall it with the same project URL, I get the following error:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ pip uninstall git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo
You must give at least one requirement to uninstall (see "pip help uninstall")
```

By the way, I'm using Python 3.7.0 (`pip` is an alias for `pip3`).

I have two questions:

1. Why is `import BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi` not working in the first place?
2. How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Are you trying to import it with the same version of python it was installed to? I mean it looks like you're using version 3.6.5, if it's installed to 3.7 then it will not see it. I've hit this many times when having more than one version installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall a package just use

```
pip uninstall BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
```

if there is some configuration issue with IPYTHON you can encounter such errors.

But if you are running short for time, i would suggest got with direct python shell command shell by using,i think this should work when you try import it into a file.

```
python <filename>.py
```

please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize [CoderRambo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6931277/coderrambo) and [tgikal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777984/tgikal)'s responses, yes, I was able to uninstall `BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi` in that fashion:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ pip uninstall BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
Uninstalling BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi-1.0.0:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi-1.0.0-py3.7.egg-info
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi/*
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/test/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi-1.0.0
```

At the root of the problem, however, was that iPython was running on Python 3.6, whereas BlueJeans was installed on Python 3.7. I confirmed this by using `which ipython`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ which ipython
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/ipython
```

I ran `pip install ipython`, and now it points to Python 3.7:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ which ipython
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ipython
```

I then re-installed the BlueJeans REST API (without specifying an egg), and now I'm able to import it:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kurtpeek$ ipython
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi

In [2]:
```