# how to install python module for specific python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

i have been trying to install module for python-3.6 through pip. i've read these post from stackoverflow and from python website, which seemed promising but they didn't worked for me.

[Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

[python website](https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html)

I've added python3.6 main folder,Scripts and Lib to PATH  and i've tried these commands.But somehow they refer to anaconda installations.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts> pip3 install xlrd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts> pip install xlrd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts> pip3.6 install xlrd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts> py -3.6 -m pip install xlrd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts> py -3 -m pip install xlrd
```

but they give same answer.

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)
```

Comment: it's already installed. Does `import xlrd` not work?

Comment: why don't you use virtualenv ? That will make your life much easier

Comment: can be possible easily if you are working in virtual environment, then you won't need to define python or pip version.

Comment: its installed in anaconda installation. python 3.6 is a seperate directory as you can see above. and i want it to be available for all programs so virtualenv is not an option

Comment: It is not about directories but about interpreters. Just do `yourpython -m pip install xlrd` where `yourpython` is the python interpreter for which you want to install xlrd.

Comment: done it already but it show it not not a recognized command

Comment: these commands are just samples. I've tried almost 20-25 commands with all the possible combination mentioned in both the links given above

Answer (score 1):

to install package for a specific python installation, you need a package installer shipped with that installation, in your case, `pip` is installed by an anaconda installation, use `pip.exe` or `easy_install.exe` from this python3.6 installation's `Scripts` directory instead.

Comment: it uses .egg format which is the old one. so i would recommend avoiding it

Answer (score 0):

First, Uninstall all the versions you have!

then go to the library https://www.python.org/downloads/

Select the required vesrsion MSI file. Run as administrator!

Answer (score 0):

i think as my python was 3.6 also my anaconda distribution, So anaconda was automatically taking over all commands. i installed python 3.7 with anaconda 3.6 and it worked fine as it was mentioned in python website