# Failing to import pyqt5 libraries on a system where both anaconda3 and python 3.5 is installed

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pyqt5

I'm new to python trying to figure out some basics. I installed python 3.5 and then, to use jupyter notebook I installed anaconda distrubition. After that, I installed pycharm and started learning python.

After a few weeks, I was able to create a simple project which makes use of pyqt5. My project runs when I run it from pycharm itself, but when I try to run it with "python" command from cmd I get an error, stating that import from pyqt5 has failed. I did some research, and installed pyqt5 using pip, but the problem persists.

So what should I do to run my project without anaconda, using python 3.5?

Comment: It seems lacking to set python path in your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the anaconda distrubution and python itself were conflicting. Whenever I tried to install a module using pip (like pyqt5), it is installed under anaconda's python so when I try to invoke my own python from console i failed to use those installed modules. Hence there seems to be two option;

1. Delete all python related stuff from the computer and clean install python only - no anaconda. (I did this)
2. Or when installing a module, try using different pip's for the two python distrubutions on our computer. Check this link: [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)