# Numpy import error even after installing it with current python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Note - I already check `numpy import error` related threads but none helped

I am using debian 8 where default python is `2.7.9`. I installed `python 3.4.2` and created virutal env.

Within virtual environment -

```
python -V
Python 3.4.2

pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /path/venv34/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

I have python3 numpy package - python3-numpy_1.12.0-2~pn0_amd64.deb

which I have installed with `sudo dpkg -i python3-numpy_1.12.0-2~pn0_amd64.deb`

which successfully completed.

Now when I do

```
python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Feb  7 2019, 06:08:06) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

Any clue what's wrong here?

Comment: You should install numpy with `pip install numpy` instead. It will add it to your python scripts folder, which is where the interpreter looks for packages.

Comment: @Jack: I need specific version of `numpy` as `numpy_1.12.0-2~pn0_amd64.deb`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

Answer (score 3):

`python3.4 -m pip install numpy==1.12.0-2`

Comment: `raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'python3-numpy_1.12.0-2~pn0_amd64.deb', 'at', '~pn0_amd64.deb')`

Answer (score 2):

Try `python -m pip install numpy==1.12.0`. This should help you.

Comment: I need specific version of `numpy` as `numpy_1.12.0-2~pn0_amd64.deb` @Mayur

Answer (score 2):

ok since my repo is less than 50 i can not add comments, so take this answer as a comment to your question.

I think numpy is installed but not in your virtualenv, make sure your virtualenv is **active** when you are trying to install any library, you will see virtualenv name in every command line if it is activated.

`(venv) C:\Users\seventeen\sprint25>`