# My pip is installing all the modules in the Python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My pip is installing all the modules in the Python3.4 version. I can not use this module in other versions.

> ImportError: No module named tensorflow

This happens with all modules. They are installing, however, only available for the Python3.4 version.

Another error that appears is as follows:

> DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the > last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python
> 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).

**NOTE:**
The problem is that the other versions I have in Python do not recognize pip and pip3. The only version that it recognizes is python3.4, so I can only add modules with this version and these modules are only available for it.

> /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
>
> /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip3
>
> $ python3 -m pip3 install numpy
>
> /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3

**NOTE:**
Another thing I've been noticing is where the Python executable is, check with the **which**:

> $ which python3.4
> /usr/bin/python3.4
>
> $ which python3.6
> /usr/local/bin/python3.6
>
> $ which python3.7
> /usr/local/bin/python3.7

The places are different, does it interfere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+different+Python+versions

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Modules get installed into a single environment. If you need them in other environments, install them there.

Comment: The problem is that the other versions I have in Python do not recognize pip and pip3. The only version that it recognizes is python3.4, so I can only add modules with this version and these modules are only available for it.

Comment: Then please read the first proposed duplicate. Its accepted answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to install VENV:

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

and then install your package with this method

```
 pip install packageName==packageVersion
```