# local pip in conda environment checks globally and says Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

create virtual environment `conda create test python=3.7`

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/mac/miniconda3/envs/test

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.7


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/osx-64::ca-certificates-2019.10.16-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-64::certifi-2019.9.11-py37_0
  libcxx             pkgs/main/osx-64::libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1
  libcxxabi          pkgs/main/osx-64::libcxxabi-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1
  libedit            pkgs/main/osx-64::libedit-3.1.20181209-hb402a30_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/osx-64::libffi-3.2.1-h475c297_4
  ncurses            pkgs/main/osx-64::ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/osx-64::openssl-1.1.1d-h1de35cc_3
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-19.3.1-py37_0
  python             pkgs/main/osx-64::python-3.7.5-h359304d_0
  readline           pkgs/main/osx-64::readline-7.0-h1de35cc_5
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-42.0.1-py37_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/osx-64::sqlite-3.30.1-ha441bb4_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/osx-64::tk-8.6.8-ha441bb4_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.33.6-py37_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::xz-5.2.4-h1de35cc_4
  zlib               pkgs/main/osx-64::zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_3
```

check the reference of `pip`, which is correct.

```
(test) mac@mac-MBP ~ % which pip
/Users/mac/miniconda3/envs/test/bin/pip
(test) mac@mac-MBP ~ % pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /Users/mac/miniconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

install `pip install jupyter`
shows

```
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.0)
```

I can use `conda` to uninstall and reinstall `pip`, which will solve the `Requirement already satisfied` issue, but it also upgrades `python3.7` to `3.8` for some reason. I have to use `3.7` because `tensorflow` currently only supports `3.7`.

Not sure what's wrong here. I have used the same commands to create environment and also worked smoothly. The only change I can think of is that I changed from bash to zsh because of Catalina. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was I installed `Jupyter` with `--user` flag before, so the package was installed in the user directory outside of the conda env directory. `pip list --user` shows these packages.

The solution is to uninstall these packages first.

```
pip freeze --user > packages.txt
pip uninstall -r packages.txt
```

Comment: How to prevent installed in the user directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `pip` with the python version you want to install the package for. For more detail please go through the link am pasting below:

[Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

and do not forget to restart your anaconda after installing.
Hope it'll solve your issue