# Error says the running Python is 3.4, but 3.5 is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I am trying to update the module vpython to the most current version. I run:

`pip3 install --user vpython --upgrade`

in a Jupyter terminal. This gives the error:

`ERROR: jupyter-server-proxy requires Python '>=3.5' but the running Python is 3.4.2`

But when I run:

`python3 --version`

it returns:

`Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)`

Is there something going wrong with the installed Python3 kernel for Jupyter?

Comment: Do `python3 -m pip install xxxx`. You're having a version conflict. Check `pip3 --version` and it will probably give you `python 3.4`. If so you might be able to use `pip3.5 install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

Answer (score 0):

Change the environmental variable in your control panel just a simple conflict between python 3.4 and 3.5 this will surely solve your issue.

Comment: No, this will possibly cause additional problems. `pip` is installed as both a binary on OP's machine and as a module in each installation of python. OP just needs to call `python -m pip install <module>` and this problem is avoided

Comment: Yes, brother, you are right but the computer must detect python 3 .5 is installed so first he must add it to the environment right??

Comment: In a standalone instance, you'd be right. But anaconda handles that in the background for you when you activate an environment, so `$PYTHONPATH` gets modified to point to that particular interpreter. The solution is that OP shouldn't be using the standalone `pip3`, but the module `pip` that's tied to the interpreter they want

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `pip3` which is not always tied to the specified `python` you are trying to run. `pip` is a module installed with each python3 instance, so to specify it to install to a python environment, use the `-m` flag:

```py
python -m pip install <module>
```

Where `python` is the `python` that you expect. For instance, if you want it to run against the installation that you use through `python3`, then you would do `python3 -m pip install <module>`. This makes things easy to track, since if you want to see which python you are installing to, you can use `python -m pip -V`. On my machine that outputs:

```py
pip 19.3.1 from /Users/mm92400/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: That seems to have done something, but when I check the version of the package, it still says 7.4, instead of 7.6, which is what I need. I am running pip with the --user flag, so is it just not updating because I don't have permissions to do it globally?

Comment: If you didn't have permissions, it should throw an error indicating so. Since it hasn't, I think you're ok for permissions. How are you checking the version of that package?

Comment: And are you using a `conda` environment or just the base install?

Comment: I used ```python3 -c "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.get_distribution('construct').version)"```

It actually appears to have updated to 7.6 now after running it again, but when I run ```import vpython``` I get an ImportError: No module named 'vpython'

Comment: Where are you running `import vpython` from?

Comment: inside a .py file, from a Jupyter Python3 notebook