# How to install pandas with pip3 for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip, python-3.5

I'm trying to install pandas for Python3. I ran the following command

```
pip3 install --user pandas
```

This worked perfectly with `numpy` instead of `pandas`.

And for `pandas` I obtain the following error that I don't know how to debug

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-1ac09uln/pandas/setup.py", line 42
       f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}",
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1ac09uln/pandas/
```

It seems that there is a syntax error in the pandas setup file... Since the problematic line is the one dealing with the minimum numpy version I checked which version I had, and it's the 1.18.2 (latest). What should I do now ?

Comment: How about: `python3 -m pip install pandas` ?

Comment: `$ sudo -H pip3 install -U pandas` ?

Comment: That's what I've done but I obtained the error I pasted in my question

Comment: Do the same with `numpy`. Don't forget the `-U` flag; that will update the package.

Comment: I obtain another syntax error `ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'` but I thought it wasn't recommended to use sudo with pip

Comment: With the `-H` flag you install it in `/usr/local`, hence not disturbing the system libs in `/usr`. ;-) Checkout `man sudo`.

Comment: You may also want to upgrade `pip` itself. And `setuptools`, maybe.

Comment: I'm unable to update pip, even using the `pip3 install --upgrade pip` command

Answer (score 1):

What version of python you have installed?Is pip updated to the latest version. f-strings where introduced in python 3.6. Maybe this is the problem. In any case it should be easier to install all packages you want using an environment like anaconda so that you can have all packages needed from the start(e.g all packages needed for data science). For an alternative you can try run pip using a specific python version(try 3.6 or greater) you can find more info for this here: [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version).