# How to Install a python package via pip in site-packages of specific python installation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-import, importerror

When I run `pip install fasteners`, it shows

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: fasteners in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from fasteners) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: monotonic>=0.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from fasteners) (1.5)
```

The package is installed in **`./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`**.

But I want to install it in `/usr/bin/python2/site-packages` ,

because `duplicity` uses python2 . And on running `duplicity --version` i get `could not import fasteners` error

Comment: I think you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Comment: What operating system or Linux distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command to install fasteners for Python 2.7:

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install fasteners
```

if you get `No module named pip` error, try:

```
sudo python2.7 -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

then try installing fasteners again.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Some other errors occurred.  Please see full output [here](https://gist.github.com/aahnik/9eab599c9c2158b2ae90df57f99de9f5#file-terminal_pip_python2-md)

Comment: Please try `sudo python2.7 -m pip uninstall pip` then installing pip with your package manager. The package might be called `python2-pip` or `python-pip`. If that doesn't work, you can try installing openssl development package and compiling python against it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I fixed the problem by removing python and having a fresh install. I had many some mistakes while installing python from source code. You were right. Actually many packages were missing

Answer (score 1):

As shared by you in comment section of @Nathan Mills's answer you are getting SSL error. I think you are missing some of the libs. Try by installing below libraries and try again with the command you were using.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall 
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Then :

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install fasteners
```

Try :

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ fasteners
```

Comment: i tried your answer. didnt work please [see output](https://gist.github.com/aahnik/9eab599c9c2158b2ae90df57f99de9f5#gistcomment-3475676)