# Python pip installing problem in ubuntu libux

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have installed python 3.9 in Ubuntu, because it comes with python 3.8 which is an older version.

I changed the command for terminal alias python 3 = python 3.9, but when I installed pip, it installed for python 3.8 and after that when I am using pip install to install python packages, it installs for python 3.8. How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Answer (score 0):

try with `pip3 install`

This kind of issue even happened to my case when I was working with the python modules recently on my project. Try this out it worked for me.

Comment: tried it says unable to locate package pip3

Answer (score 0):

Due to variations in the installation process of python, pip often requires different ways to access for different people. A few examples that may help you include `pip3 install`, `py pip install` `py -3 pip install` or `python3 pip install`. Usually one of these works for me.