# How do I install python-telegram-bot to python 3.10.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

After running `pip3 install python-telegram-bot` in command prompt, I get `'telegram' module is not found` when I run `python -m telegram` after the installation.

I have Python 3.9 and 3.10.1 installed, and it seems like the package is installed in the Python 3.9 directory as the output during the installation shows `...pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9`

I am new to programming, so I am at a lost as to how to install it for Python 3.10.1. Appreciate any guidance I can get.

Comment: What if you run `python3 -m telegram`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

Comment: @RJAdriaansen It showed: `The system cannot find the file...` Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @CallMeStag Not exactly. Calling the Python version didn't work for me. It showed: `The system cannot find the file...` But reading the post helped me to understand what was wrong. Now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed the module through `pip3` there is a chance you just need to use `python3`. Try `python3 -m telegram`.
Opposite it might be that you need to use `pip install python-telegram-bot` for it to work with `python`.
Usually `pip` is linked to `python` and `pip3` is linked to `python3` but it is only a guideline, not a rule.

If that doesn't work you can always invoke pip for the other python binary with `python -m pip install python-telegram-bot`

Comment: `python -m pip install python-telegram-bot` worked for me as that is the path that is recognised as where my latest version of Python 3.10.1 is installed. Thanks a lot @Mikael.

Comment: For anyone using PyCharm who still gets `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'` after successfully installing it, remember to check on **Inherit global site-packages** when creating a new project.