# How can I ensure my Python packages are installed in Python 3.10 instead of /Library/Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have successfully installed Python 3.10. I want to install packages. Pandas, BeautifulSoup4, and requests.

I tried to import NumPy but IDE says it doesn't have the NumPy module.

I searched for it in directories and it turned out NumPy is in the 3.8 version.

I used the command on the terminal:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install Pandas
```

Which installed it successfully.

But the package files are installed in Python 3.8.

Now I have the following Directories:

- /Library/Python  3.8
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions    3.10
- /Applications/Python 3.10
- /usr/local/bin   3.10

In /Library/Python there is only 2.7 and 3.8 versions

[image: Python 3.8]

In following directories version is 3.10:

- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions    3.10
- /Applications/Python 3.10
- /usr/local/bin   3.10

/usr/local/bin

[image: /usr/local/bin]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

[image: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions]

/Applications/Python

[image: /Applications/Python]

What will happen if i remove 3.8 or can i update it to 3.10?

Comment: When you try `python3` by itself, what version of Python gets run (according to the welcome message in the interpreter)? Anyway, as a rule *do not ever remove any version of Python that came pre-installed on your computer*. There is no telling what might be dependent on it. Anyway, it's not clear what your **question** is. Did you actually mean "how can I ensure that a package is installed in 3.10"? "How can I start the 3.10 interpreter explicitly"? "How can I ensure that a script is executed using 3.10"? Something else?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel when i run python on ide or terminal it says 3.10.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If it is not recommended to uninstall pre loaded python then how can i ensure that my packages are install in 3.10 instead of 3.8.

Comment: If that's the question, then you should *explicitly ask it*, in the post itself.

Answer (score 1):

Is better to use a virtual environment and install in it python 3.10, removing Python 3.8 can may some problems, so avoid removing it, and if you are open to using different tools, I advise you to use Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

### **Don't follow this (go to EDIT instead):**

I found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25123329/13377578

Just had to specify the version of Python I want to install the package in.

```
sudo python3.10 -m pip install Pandas
```

Now it works. Thanks.

### **EDIT:**

Thanks for the comments below. I am new to Python and didn't know what environments were.

I followed this simple [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-104c62d48c54).

I made an environment for my project (my system-level python is now safe from messing up) and now everything works.

Create Environment:

```
cd python-projects

Python3.10 - m venv Venv_Name

source pit-ds/bin/activate
```

Installing Packages:

```
pip list

pip install Pandas

pip install BeautifulSoup4

pip install Requests
```

Run IDLE within Virtual Environment:

```
python -m idlelib.idle
```

Deactivating Environment:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: you probably don't want sudo...

Comment: No, that's wrong! Don't install anything into your system python3.10. You *have to* use venv, its super easy! `python3.10 -m venv venv` then `source venv/bin/activate` then `pip install pandas`.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Thanks for teaching me something new. @psarka

Comment: Never, ever use `sudo` with pip. The [makers of PIP themselves warn about this in no uncertain language](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599)

Comment: Before posting the question I was researching this and someone in a different question's answer suggested sudo. Thanks, I didn't know that. @Brian

Comment: @DanishArain Awesome, I'm glad you paid attention to advice! I take back my -1 and replace it by +1.