# i keep getting this massege "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'" whenever i try to import it eventhough i have installed it, why is that?

Tags: python, import, module, pip, pygame

python, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame', pip

in the command prompt, it says "Requirement already satisfied" but when trying to import, I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably multiple python versions installed. But 'pip' only installed the package for one of those versions.

You can specify the python version like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

`python[your version] -m pip install [package]`

This will install 'pygame' for python 3.10:

`python3.10 -m pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

U may have to install pygame using pip. If you have already done that then it should work. If pip is not recognized then open windows run and type %appdata% u have to reinstall python with pip and add it to your enviroment path. It must work