# Terminal can't find version of python despite it being installed

Tags: python, module, version

I'm trying to install packages on multiple versions of Python. I'm currently running 3.8.8, and 3.11.0.

Following this post [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)
called

`python3.11 -m pip install pandas`

which results in

`File "<stdin>", line 1 python3.11 -m pip install pandas SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

This seems to indicate an issue with python, so I double checked that python3.11 is installed.

the python3.11 works in isolation seems to work.

I don't understand why the install command isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Linux try just

```
python3 —-version
```

In Windows you may need to add path to folder with installed Python to PATH variable.