# Mercurial, TortoiseHg, keyring and using two remote repos with two usernames and passwords being forgotten

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHg Workbench 64bit 2.1.4, though it may be an issue with Mercurial. The OS is Windows 7 (64bit).

I have two projects that I push to two different locations (one is bitbucket, the other is an private one). They use different usernames and passwords, and I push over HTTPS.

I have setup the keyring in my mercurial.ini:

```
[extensions]
mercurial_keyring=
```

and in the two .hg/hgrc files, I have setup paths with their respective values:

```
[paths]
default = https://userX@domainX/XXX
```

If I only work on one repo, the password is remembered each time I connect. However, when I switch between projects, I have to re-enter the password. It's as if it will only remember one password.

Below is an example log with teh --debug option (the password is prompted after the line saying 'user: userX (fixed in .hg/hgrc)':

```
% hg --repository xxx push --debug https://userX@domainX/XXX
pushing to https://userX@domainX/XXX
using https://userX@domainX/XXX
http auth: user userX, password not set
sending capabilities command
domainX certificate successfully verified
Keyring URL: https://userX@domainX/XXX
Keyring password found. Url: https://userX@domainX/XXX, user: userX, passwd: ********
domainX certificate successfully verified
Keyring URL: https://userX@domainX/XXX
http authorization required
realm: DEV
user: userX (fixed in .hg/hgrc)
Saving password for userX to keyring
Manually entered password. Url: https://userX@domainX/XXX, user: userX, passwd: ********
domainX certificate successfully verified
sending heads command
Keyring URL: https://userX@domainX/XXX
Cached auth data found. Url: https://userX@domainX/XXX, user: userX, passwd: ********
domainX certificate successfully verified
searching for changes
no changes found
checking for updated bookmarks
sending listkeys command
Keyring URL: https://userX@domainX/XXX
Cached auth data found. Url: https://userX@domainX/XXX, user: userX, passwd: ********
domainX certificate successfully verified
```

Comment: can you show log of `hg in --debug` for both repos?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the log, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried on my Windows-machine, and I can reproduce but have no fix. Looks like the keyring extension indeed only stores one password and it gets replaced when you store another. If you go to Windows’s Credential Manager you can see this happening.

There is an existing bug report in the Python keyring library that the Mercurial keyring extension uses:

https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib/issue/47/winvaultkeyring-only-ever-returns-last

Looks like one of the developers replied to it just yesterday, so maybe he is working on a fix.

**Edit**: According to the bug report this is now fixed, and according to Lee Atkinson it is now also working in TortoiseHg.

Comment: The userX@ part is required. Otherwise it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I have tried without userX@ and also specifying default.username within the [auth] section of .hg/hgrc, but neither makes a difference

Comment: This is within TortoiseHg Workbench (i've updated my question to include this information)

Comment: I replaced my useless answer with a more useful, though probably unsatisfying one.

Comment: I also filed https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial_keyring/issue/12/keyring-extension-only-remembers-1 on the Mercurial keyring extension project.

Comment: Aha @LaurensHolst .Thanks for identifying this and following it up.

Comment: I can confirm that this is now indeed fixed - also in the tortoisehg.