# hg push error and username not specified in .hg/hgrc. Keyring will not be used

Tags: authentication, mercurial, ldap, credentials, mercurial-keyring

I did the following:

hg clone ...somelink.to.repo.in.hg... Giga

cd Giga

ls                     (...it shows me giga.txt file exist in Giga directory)

vi giga.txt            (...made some changes..)

hg commit -m "byte"

hg out                 (got the following error)

```
** unknown exception encountered, details follow
** report bug details to http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/
** or mercurial@selenic.com
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.5)
** Extensions loaded: acl, bugzilla, children, churn, color, convert, extdiff, fetch, gpg, graphlog, hgcia, hgk, highlight, interhg, keyword, mercurial_keyring, mq, notify, pager, patchbomb, progress, purge, rebase, record, relink, schemes, share, transplant, zeroconf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 27, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 16, in run
    sys.exit(dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 30, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(u, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 47, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(ui, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 466, in _dispatch
    return runcommand(lui, repo, cmd, fullargs, ui, options, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 336, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 128, in wrap
    return wrapper(origfn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hgext/pager.py", line 66, in pagecmd
    return orig(ui, options, cmd, cmdfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 517, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 471, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 465, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 116, in wrap
    util.checksignature(origfn), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hgext/color.py", line 352, in nocolor
    return orig(*args, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 116, in wrap
    util.checksignature(origfn), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hgext/mq.py", line 2648, in mqcommand
    return orig(ui, repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 116, in wrap
    util.checksignature(origfn), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hgext/graphlog.py", line 365, in graph
    return orig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 2275, in outgoing
    other = hg.repository(cmdutil.remoteui(repo, opts), dest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 82, in repository
    repo = _lookup(path).instance(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 271, in instance
    inst.between([(nullid, nullid)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 190, in between
    d = self.do_read("between", pairs=n)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 134, in do_read
    fp = self.do_cmd(cmd, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/httprepo.py", line 85, in do_cmd
    resp = self.urlopener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 429, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 855, in http_error_401
    url, req, headers)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mercurial_keyring.py", line 339, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 833, in http_error_auth_reqed
    return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 836, in retry_http_basic_auth
    user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(realm, host)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mercurial_keyring.py", line 333, in find_user_password
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mercurial_keyring.py", line 184, in find_auth
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mercurial_keyring.py", line 67, in get_http_password
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keyring/core.py", line 37, in get_password
    return _keyring_backend.get_password(service_name, username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 143, in get_password
    items = gnomekeyring.find_network_password_sync(username, service)
gnomekeyring.IOError
```

### My ~/.hgrc (OpenSUSE machine)

```
[ui]
username=c123456 <Arun.Sangal@MyCompany.com>

[extensions]
mercurial_keyring = /root/mercurial_keyring.py

#[trusted]
#users = *
#groups = *

[extensions]
acl =
bugzilla =
children =
churn =
color =
convert =
eol = !
extdiff =
factotum = !
fetch =
gpg =
graphlog =
hgcia =
hgcr-gui-qt = !
hgk =
highlight =
interhg =
keyword =
largefiles = !
mercurial_keyring =
mq =
notify =
pager =
patchbomb =
perfarce = !
progress =
projrc = !
purge =
rebase =
record =
relink =
schemes =
```

....
........etc

---

My local repository 
(on OpenSuse cloned folder - inside: /Giga/.hg/hgrc) is:

---

```
[paths]
default = http://the.hg.server.com/hg/TestHgRepo1/
myrepo = http://the.hg.server.com/hg/TestHgRepo1/

[auth]
myrepo.schemes = http https
myrepo.prefix = the.hg.server.com/hg
myrepo.username = c123456
```

---

I tried everything but this Keyring thing is not working. I get prompt everytime I do:

- hg out
- hg push
- etc hg operation but not when I do

hg commit

Can someone please tell what the heck I'm missing here. Tried the same excercise on Windows with TortoiseHg, with C:...\mercurial.ini (Windows side kinda of unix ~/.hgrc file).. and updated/made sure local repository cloned folder's ../clonedfolder/.hg/hgrc file contains the similar [auth] ..3 lines but Mercurial on Linux OpenSUSE and on Windows using TortoiseHg is not working with keyring.

It's prompting me for entering user credentials again n again :((

can someone pls correct me on what should I do to get this resolved.

Comment: See these links for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267873/mercurial-hg-no-changes-found-cant-hg-push-out/14269997#14269997 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4867412#post4867412

Answer (score 6):

if prompted multiple times for user credentials in mercurial. Setup Mercurial_Keyring and then

this question comes which nobody explained in an easy way.

??? how to make the [auth] xx.prefix = servername/hg_or_something work for all repositories under servername/hg location either if I use servername, servername's IP or servername's FQDN ?

Final ANSWER: Arun • 2 minutes ago −

OK, I put this in ~/.hgrc (Linux/Unix -home directory's .hgrc hidden file) or Windows users %UserProfile%/mercurial.ini or %HOME%/mercurial.ini file.

```
[auth]
default1.schemes = http https
default1.prefix = hg_merc_server/hg
default1.username = c123456

default2.schemes = http https
default2.prefix = hg_merc_server.company.com/hg
default2.username = c123456

default3.schemes = http https
default3.prefix = 10.211.222.321/hg
default3.username = c123456
```

Now, I can checkout using either Server/IP/Server's FQDN.

Comment: What is "default1" in that example?

Comment: `default1` is just a key. Use anything.