# Mercurial Hg No changes found - can't Hg push out

Tags: linux, mercurial, push, output, mercurial-keyring

Can someone pls advise why I'm getting NO CHANGES found at the end.

Also, I'm getting an annoying message, "**Username not specified in .hg/hgrc. Keyring will not be used.**"

Version tool: Hg latest version
Server: Linux
Workspace: ~/2012WS

```
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS # hg clone http://LinuxServer123/hg/GigaTest/
    Username not specified in .hg/hgrc. Keyring will not be used.
    http authorization required
    realm: Mercurial Repositories
    user: u123456
    password:
    destination directory: GigaTest
    requesting all changes
    adding changesets
    adding manifests
    adding file changes
    added 14 changesets with 585 changes to 575 files (+1 heads)
    2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
    updating to branch default
    0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS #

    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS # cd GigaTest/
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest # ls -tlr
    total 12
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   25 Jan 10 16:36 hello.py
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   25 Jan 10 16:36 HELLO-UP.PY
    drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 10 16:36 .hg
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest # vi hello.py
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest # ls -l > new.txt
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest # hg add new.txt
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest #

    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest #
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest # hg stat
    M hello.py
    A new.txt
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest #

    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest # hg out
    comparing with http://LinuxServer123/hg/GigaTest/
    Username not specified in .hg/hgrc. Keyring will not be used.
    http authorization required
    realm: Mercurial Repositories
    user: u123456
    password:
    searching for changes
    no changes found
    LinuxServer123:~/2012WS/GigaTest #
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You have to do `hg commit` first.

`hg stat` shows the changes made to the current working repository (since the last commit) and `hg out` shows the commits made to your repository that will be pushed out on `hg push`.

And the message "Username not specified in .hg/hgrc" means that your username is not specified in the .hg/hgrc file. Keyring is an extension I'm not familiar with; presumably it will take your username and do something with a key.

Comment: no changes found issue is gone. thanks. But i see the following while "hg push".  remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
remote: abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes). remote: warning: changegroup hook exited with status 255 .....................By the way, what's .hg/.hgrc .. the file in ~/home directory?

Comment: You're going to need to do a merge. I don't know what the "changegroup hook" is; you'll need to talk to the admin about that.

Comment: You may want to look at these. They've helped me: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tutorial http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read

Comment: The `.hg/hgrc` file should be in the root directory of the repository. So in your example, that file should be at `~/2012WS/GigaTest/.hg/hgrc`. There should also be a file at `~/.hgrc` (in your home directory) which has more global settings for Mercurial.

Comment: What if I'm setting Hg/Mercurial setup on a virutal server (cluster environment) where I dont have a USER's home ~ directory. In that case, which file will hold the "more global" settings for mercurial?