# Hg extensions + merge tool on mac os x

Tags: macos, mercurial

I am working on setup of my hg for django projects on my mac.

I need to do two things :

- set some mechanism to save my password and use it whenever I use repo again

I've tried to do that by adding **keyring extension** to my .hg/hgrc file like this :

```
[extensions]
mercurial_keyring =
```

but it doesn't work. I am getting such an error :

```
*** failed to import extension mercurial_keyring: No module named mercurial_keyring
```

Should I install that extension with pip / easy_install before?

Because on Windows using HgTortoise I modified my hgrd file, added those two lines and it works just fine.

I thought it would do the work on mac os x as well.

- set some default merge-tool, which would be launched whenever I use **hg merge** command and there would be some confilicts to resolve

How can I do that?

Here is my current hg files configuration :

~/.hgrc

```
[ui]
username = johny bravo <johny.bravo@gmail.com>
```

.../myproject/.hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/johnybravo/firstdjango

[extensions]
mercurial_keyring =
```

According to some tutorials and articles about hg I'd read before that should do the work.

But doesn't work in my case.

Btw. Is there any nice external merge tool for hg? Vimdiff is terrible for me...

I also use SourceTree for version control sometimes, but it seems it doesn't contain any merge tool.

Is there any tool that looks similar to SourceTree? ( nice, readable, colorful GUI ).

A perfect merge-tool would be one compatibile both with SourceTree and hg merge from command line so I coulde use them alternately.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [Keyring extension wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeyringExtension)

> This extension is not distributed with Mercurial

thus: adding extension to hgrc without full path or some preliminary action will not work, as you saw

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653223) demonstrate correct full pip-type install of Keyring

About "nice external merge tool for hg?" I have to say "Tastes can differ", but any diff-merge tool, which works of Mac, can be used in Mercurial

- From my POV, [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/) isn't terrible
- [DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/) suggested as "Beyond Compare for Mac" by [some users](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-apps-games/99976-looking-mac-equivalent-beyond-compare.html)
- [P4Merge](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/p4merge) for Mac

Answer (score 0):

[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/johnybravo/firstdjango

---

add:
"default-push = https://username:password@bitbucket.org/johnybravo/firstdjango"
without quotes.

using ssh is another more involved set up way to push without username/password entry.