# NPM package url as dependency in mercurial(bitbucket)

Tags: git, mercurial, package, npm

I have searched this topic for long time, currently all the solutions and examples work in git, but no direct solution for **Mercurial**.

Working example taken from somewhere similar links.

```
"private": true
to your package.json

Then to reference private npm module in package.json

{
    "name": "myapp",
    "dependencies": {
        "private-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git#v1.0.0",
    }
}
```

As I read from official npm page this all works only with git 
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

So how to do the same thing in Mercurial or currently it's seems to be possible only with Git ?

Comment: There is no actual question in your question.

Comment: yes, my mistake added last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPM supports git but does not support Mercurial.  You could use something like Kiln to host your repository, which allows access as either Mercurial or git, but failing that you'll have to clone into local and point NPM at that.

Answer (score 11):

If you *are* using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) to host your project's Mercurial repo, it does provide links to download snapshots of your project as a tar.gz file. These URLs [are actually usable](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#URLs-as-Dependencies) in `package.json` dependencies.

For example, my `pagedown` project's [download page](https://bitbucket.org/ncraike/pagedown/downloads#branch-downloads) has a link to this URL for a gzipped snapshot of the latest `default` branch changes:

```
https://bitbucket.org/ncraike/pagedown/get/default.tar.gz
```

so in another project's `package.json`, I can specify:

```
"dependencies": {
    "pagedown": "https://bitbucket.org/ncraike/pagedown/get/default.tar.gz"
}
```

npm handles this fine when I do an `npm install` from the dependent package, installing it correctly to the `node_modules` subdirectory.

This isn't a general solution for Mercurial repositories (and I agree it'd be nice if npm accepted Mercurial URLs as well) but this could be a reasonable workaround if you're using Bitbucket or a similar site for hosting.

Comment: It appears that you can use this to retrieve a specific version by using the following syntax along with version tags:
https://bitbucket.org/USERNAME/MODULENAME/get/TAG.tar.gz
You can find these URLs on the downloads page under the tags tab.

Comment: Ah. Actually, yes, specific versions would probably be preferred, so your dependencies are stable and tested and don't change unexpectedly (eg whenever someone commits to default).

Comment: For private repos, how would I provide credentials without placing them into the package.json?

Comment: @kierans I have no idea if this would work, but my first instinct is to try adding `[auth]` section to `~/.hgrc` Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584407/how-to-save-username-and-password-with-mercurial#2589195