# hgrc configuration for maven-release-plugin

Tags: mercurial, maven-archetype

I'm creating a new custom maven archetype for android... it's installed and working.

But where I try use `mvn release:perform`, I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] pushing to http://code.programadoremjava.com.br/android-archetype
[DEBUG] searching for changes
[DEBUG] ignoring invalid [auth] key 'username'
[DEBUG] ignoring invalid [auth] key 'password'
[DEBUG] abort: http authorization required for http://code.programadoremjava.com.br/android-archetype
```

The project hgrc is here:

```
[paths]
default = http://code.programadoremjava.com.br/android-archetype
[auth]
username=MyUser
password=MyPass
```

What are wrong/missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[paths]
default = http://code.programadoremjava.com.br/android-archetype

[auth]
repo.prefix = http://code.programadoremjava.com.br/android-archetype
repo.username = MyUser
repo.password = MyPass
```

Much more details you can find here: [How to save username and password with Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584407/how-to-save-username-and-password-with-mercurial)