# SourceTree - Mercurial - Authentication - requesting user name and password each time?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I use SourceTree with a local Mercurial server, the problem is that SourceTree is asking to authenticate at each operation. By example, for a clone it can be 10 times entering user/pwd ...

Though, I enter user/pwd and checked the "remember" checkbox, it continue to ask.

I have see that I can use SSH, but I have no access to the repository web page (it is a local server) to setup the SSH key.

1 - I tried to setup an account in SourceTree using Options>Authentication
Using the option "Bitbucket server" and entering our server URL. In fact, with this method I can even enter my password, it just failed !

2 - By using an URL like this : https://username:password@serverurl

3 - Using the Windows Credentials Manager !

4 - I edited the .hgrc file

Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save username and password with Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584407/how-to-save-username-and-password-with-mercurial)

Comment: Hi, it is not a duplicate because all the proposed solution does not work here !!

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to say more without knowing what about them doesn't work, because these are the normal ways of automating authentication in Mercurial.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited the question to add more information. All I want is to connect to my local mercurial repo with entering the user name and password each time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve the issue, then I use TortoiseHG and this tool works !
So, it looks like a bug in SourceTree !

You can also switch for SourceTree version 1.6.23, this one will work.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-discussions/Git-Credential-Manager/m-p/580591#M4) on the Atlassian Community solved the issue for me (edited for typos and clarity):

> For all who are using SourceTree under Windows OS and Mercurial as Versioning tool and want to get rid of the boring popup asking for your credentials:
>
> 1. Start cmd shell as admin
> 2. Change path to where git-credential-manager.exe as been installed (normaly under ~\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_extras)
> 3. Call "git-credential-manager.exe store"
> 4. In the next lines fill in:
>      protocol=https
>      host=code.domain.name
>      username=yourLoginName
>      password=yourLoginPassword
> 5. Press return again for a new empty line. If you don't get any message, everything is okay.